# How to deploy an app with my fork of a package via Yarn and Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, yarnpkg

I'm using Capistrano to deploy my Rails app.

`assets:precompile` fails because of using an old code. Why doesn't it use freshly installed yarn package?

---

I have forked `@fancyapps/fancybox` repo to solve [this issue](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/issues/2153).

1. Touched one file.
2. Ran `gulp` task.
3. Pushed to my fork to the new branch called `unquote-max-css-function`

Now it's time to use it in my project.

Ran `yarn upgrade git+ssh://git@github.com:light-flight/fancybox.git#unquote-max-css-function`

Locally it works - all code bundles successfully. But in production it's using old assets during `assets:precompile` (see logs below).

I am sure Yarn bundled my repo because it had asked access rights before.

production error:

```sh
...

00:24 yarn:install
      01 yarn install --production
      01 yarn install v1.12.3
      01 [1/4] Resolving packages...
      01 [2/4] Fetching packages...
      01 warning Pattern ["animate.css@latest"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/home/deploy/.cache/yarn/v4/npm-animate-css-3.7.0-5de25d…
      01 info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
      01 info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
      01 [3/4] Linking dependencies...
      01 warning "@rails/webpacker > pnp-webpack-plugin > ts-pnp@1.1.2" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@*".
      01 warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
      01 warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.6.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
      01 [4/4] Building fresh packages...
      01 Done in 15.13s.
00:41 deploy:assets:precompile
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
      01 yarn install v1.12.3
      01 [1/4] Resolving packages...
      01 success Already up-to-date.
      01 Done in 1.30s.
      01 rake aborted!
      01 SassC::SyntaxError: Error: "env(safe-area-inset-right)" is not a number for `max'
      01         on line 11366 of stdin, in function `max`
      01         from line 11366 of stdin
      01 >>     padding: 75px max(44px, env(safe-area-inset-right)) max(25px, env(safe-a
      01    ------------------^
      01 stdin:11366
      01 /home/deploy/apps/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sassc-2.0.1/lib/sassc/engine.rb:49:in `render'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sassc-rails-2.1.1/lib/sassc/rails/compressor.rb:29:in `call'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'

...
```

As you can see it tries to compile old code with unquoted `max` function.

Locally it compiles successfully:

```sh
$ rails assets:precompile
yarn install v1.15.2
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 1.42s.
I, [2019-05-05T13:02:34.620408 #10872]  INFO -- : Writing /home/user/apps/app/public/assets/application-6f331dc14f50de04a8e7dd5d4c4882ffbf78cefc5ac4d73294ea48912d74a2a5.css
I, [2019-05-05T13:02:34.620871 #10872]  INFO -- : Writing /home/user/apps/app/public/assets/application-6f331dc14f50de04a8e7dd5d4c4882ffbf78cefc5ac4d73294ea48912d74a2a5.css.gz
```

I've tried to `yarn cache clean` but nothing changed. How to force rails to use my fork?

Comment: Have you found a resolution for this issue? We're having the same problem but we aren't using yarn. We're using sprockets < 4 and sass-rails < 6.0.0.

Comment: @curtp No. I could not use my fork